# How to make black box in this image with one side free line in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make a black box in this image with one side free line in the flutter.

[image]

Comment: You have changed your question

Comment: I am sorry I was unable to tell my question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make an SVG of the background you want (in that case this shape) and then make a stack where I have the SVG Picture kind of in the background and then I position the other widgets on top of that. If that is what you mean I recommend you to get into SvgPicture.asset... that's what I mostly use. For the Stack, you just write the Stack then children, in that you put a Container with the SvgPicture.asset as the child and then use the Positioned widget to put the other widgets (in this case some text and container widgets) on top... I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Clipper and a [bezier curve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html). [Here](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/36/how-to-make-bezier-curve-waves-using-custom-clip-path-in-flutter/) you can find a good example, but the general idea is to create a Container with your desired color, wrap that in a Clipper and implement the bezier curve yourself with that clipper.

The following is not my code, but taken from the link mentioned above:

```
class WaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
 @override
 Path getClip(Size size) {

  var path = new Path();
  path.lineTo(0, size.height); //start path with this if you are making at bottom
  
  var firstStart = Offset(size.width / 5, size.height); 
  //fist point of quadratic bezier curve
  var firstEnd = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 50.0);
  //second point of quadratic bezier curve
  path.quadraticBezierTo(firstStart.dx, firstStart.dy, firstEnd.dx, firstEnd.dy);

  var secondStart = Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.24), size.height - 105); 
  //third point of quadratic bezier curve
  var secondEnd = Offset(size.width, size.height - 10);
  //fourth point of quadratic bezier curve
  path.quadraticBezierTo(secondStart.dx, secondStart.dy, secondEnd.dx, secondEnd.dy);

  path.lineTo(size.width, 0); //end with this path if you are making wave at bottom
  path.close();
  return path; 
 }

 @override
 bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
  return false; //if new instance have different instance than old instance 
  //then you must return true;
 }
}
```

[image: Code from Fluttercampus]

Comment: Should you please make a exact design as in the question. I am unable to make that design by my own.